# For ML.NET - MLContext, CreateDatabaseLoader<T>(), is there an attribute or method to ignore Fields/Properties on a input Class for T?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ml.net

I am looking for a hopeful method to have the MLContext CreateDatabaseLoader() method automatically ignore properties on a class similar to the DbContext for EntityFramework `[NotMapped]` or for Json `[JsonIgnore]`

consider the following simplified model code, I am hoping for something for the **magical attribute**

```
public class Position{
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Person{
  public string FullName { get; set; }
  public int CurrentAge { get; set; }
  public string BirthCity { get; set;}
  public string BirthCountry { get; set; }
  
  [magical attribute]
  [JsonIgnore]
  public Position PrimaryPosition { get; set; }
}
```

this is the execution code

```
  //_mlContext is a Microsoft.ML.Context
  //_dbContext is a Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
 
  var loader = _mlContext.Data.CreateDatabaseLoader<Person>();
  DatabaseSource dbSource = new DatabaseSource(SomeDbFactory.Instance,   _dbContext.Database.GetConnectionString(), "SELECT * from person");
  IDataView dataView = loader.Load(dbSource);
```

The execution gives the following error at `CreateDatabaseLoader`:
`Specified method is not supported.`
From the stack trace:

```
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.DbExtensions.ToDbType(InternalDataKind dataKind)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.DatabaseLoader.CreateDatabaseLoader[TInput](IHostEnvironment host)
   at Microsoft.ML.DatabaseLoaderCatalog.CreateDatabaseLoader[TInput](DataOperationsCatalog catalog)
```

Diving into the `ToDbType` and other related code it seems to try to convert to more primitive types (from 20 minutes of looking), so obviously it wouldn't convert the `Position` class object. If I create a `SimplePerson` class that does not have the `Position` Property, it executes fine.
Tried searching around the GitHub documentation and other resources but I cannot find any examples of attribute usage or more complex Models than simple "hello world" equivalent tutorials. If anyone has any good (more complex) resources please link them.

I am trying to continue using the same Model Class that I use for my DbContext, with some additions of attributes. My secondary option would be to create some reflective wrapper that creates a simplified class of each Model that does not include any class or complex Property references, as the overall Model structure is fairly large and I would prefer runtime automation to creating double classes for everything, which then has to be maintained.